# android: how to change the back arrow shape?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-actionbar

I am currently working on an android app and I want to change the look of the back button.
it currently looks like that:

[image]

but I want the arrow to look like in this actionbar:

[image]

How can I change it? by the way, I am using AppCompat light theme.

Answer (score 1):

extend this theme, and change the back icon on your theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/my_indicator_image</item>
</style>
```

then use you own theme

Comment: Thanks. but where can I find an indicator image that is identical to the one I want?

Comment: Download the images from here http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html Its free and from google itself

Comment: Thank you. I did your steps, but now the MainActivity icon changed too to that arrow. how can I fix this?